# How to create an opencl project for any gpu?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, opencl, project, gpgpu

I want to create an opencl project on VS2015 for any gpu. There are different PCs in the team with different GPUs (nVidia, Intel and ATI) . I want to create a project which can be compiled and launched by any member of the team.

What is the best way?

1. Project settings are the same for everyone based on environment variables which are set locally
2. Creating new solution configuration, different project settings for every configuration ( we have six configurations/platforms now and do not really want to have more )
3. Some magic with DLLs in run-time

Thanks,

Frankie

Comment: then send string to them, they compile on their computer

Comment: Require everyone to install the Intel OpenCL CPU runtime or the Intel OpenCL SDK, it provides OpenCL 2.1 support. That way, you have all the functions available so there won't be any random crashes when someone using NVIDIA runs code that checks OpenCL 2 functions. The OpenCL library that you link against doesn't control what devices you can access (as long as it supports the OpenCL version you want to use). For example, if having both NVIDIA and Intel OpenCL runtimes installed and linking against the Intel one, the NVIDIA GPUs are still accessible.